# Click to heal addon

Tags: mods, warhammer-online

Is there an addon for Warhammer Online that allows me to click to heal somebody when I click on their hp bar?

In this case I'm using YakUI, which uses the Squared add on to handle unit frames, so working with squared is a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer that works in my case, but other answers wouldn't hurt.

I ended up using the addon **SquaredClick** which allows you to bind abilities to clicks on the squared interface, including modified clicks (shift, ctrl, shift+ctrl, etc.).

Really helpful when healing a warband, since now you can just click on a name that's losing hp and watch the little bars fill up (hopefully)